# Javascript html reflow count

Tags: javascript, reflow

I'm wondering if it's worth it to optimize some simple code like this:

```
var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
var y1 = $div1.offset().top;
var h1 = $div1.outerHeight(true);
var w1 = $div1.outerWidth(true);
```

How many reflows are we doing? Will browsers pack them all together into 1 reflow or will that cause 4 reflows?

Comment: Have you checked using your browser’s developer tools …?

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding correctly but aren't you accessing the DOM readonly in your code above?

Answer (score 0):

This code *could* cause up to 4 reflows. Any time you take a measurement that must be calculated it can cause reflows, such as accessing offsetWidth, clientHeight, or any computed CSS value, while DOM changes are queued up to be made.. That being said some browsers may do work behind the scenes to avoid multiple reflows happening in some cases.

All that aside one thing I have learned, unless you have viewed this code causing serious performance issues while testing, don't be premature in performance optimization.

To answer another portion of your question without seeing more code its hard to say if its worth optimizing that bit but most likely its not with the little I have seen. Although me, I would have written it like this from the start:

```
var offset = $div1.offset();
var x1 = offset.left;
var y1 = offset.top;
var h1 = $div1.outerHeight(true);
var w1 = $div1.outerWidth(true);
```